# Why is my track not following the curve profile?

Tags: modifiers

My track wraps correctly to the curve profile. However, when I move it, it partially follows the profile then goes 'tangent'. I have checked my curves, it does not have any loose points. Am I doing anything wrong in transformation constraint?

Attaching snapshots for your easy reference. Help is greatly appreciated! Thank you!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your curve isn't closed. You have to click on "cyclic" to make it work.

[image]